# Walk through on Distributive Property Discrete Mathematics Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, normal-distribution

sorry for the fundamental question, but can someone please help me understand how this problem was simplified in these three lines? Step 1 to step 2 seems fairly obvious if I understand it correctly, though how does placing that invisible integer there help in the overall simplification? My main confusion comes from step 2 to 3. Again, sorry for the rather basic question, but clearing this up will greatly help me work through these problems in the future.

> $\begin{array}{rlr}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(i !) & =\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(i !)+(k+1)((k+1) !) & \\ & =[(k+1) !-1]+(k+1)((k+1) !) &  \text { Since } P(k) \text { is true } \\ & =1 \cdot(k+1) !-1+(k+1)((k+1) !) & \\ & =(1+(k+1)) \cdot(k+1) !-1 & \text { Distributive property }  \\ \end{array}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only the plenty of expressions containing $k$ might distract you a bit.

In such a case you may replace given expressions by simple variables to see what actually happens as in your case between step 2 and 3.

For example: Just for the time being set $b=(k+1)!$ and $a=(k+1)$, then you see from $2$ to $3$ the following happens

$$b - 1 + ab = b+ab -1 = (1+a)b - 1$$

Comment: Very well put, I did not think of using other variables to simplify this, but I can now see how this strategy is helpful. I appreciate your response!

Comment: @skepticalforever : Thank you for giving feedback. Because in this type of question it is often not completely clear, whether one has really addressed the problem. If you are fine with this answer, it would be good to tag it as accepted answer.

Comment: Lastly, if you don't mind the additional help: the larger part of this problem was to show that: k+1Σi=1|i(i!)=((k+1)+1)!-1                                                                           I can see now how the problem was simplified to come to the conclusion, but getting there often confuses me. Is there an overall strategy to knowing how to simplify these questions in order to get them in the correct format, or is it simply a matter of practice. Pardon me if this question does not make much sense.

Comment: Of course, it is a matter of practice and especially when proving by induction, the means to apply within the induction step ($P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$) depend heavily on the structure of the statement $P(k)$.

But a good idea is always to keep clearly in mind how $P(k+1)$ looks like. This often somehow dictates (as in your case) in what direction to head, as in your example. You needed to squeeze out a factor $(k+2)$. So, it is quite natural to look for a $k+1$ and a $1$.

Comment: Very much appreciated, I will keep these tips with me moving forward :)